# QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QAbstractListModel*'

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I'm trying to create a custom `QQuickItem` for displaying charts in my application.  My C++ version is working, but I cannot get my Python version to work.  I believe this is because `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `qRegisterMetaType` aren't ported to PySide2.  While my example below doesn't demostrate this, my requirements are that the pie chart isn't static (it can change at anytime) and that I can have any number of pie charts that can be added or removed during runtime.

My program will run, but it doesn't display anything and I get the following error on the console:

```
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QAbstractListModel*' for property 'CustomPieChart::model'
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QAbstractListModel*' for property 'CustomPieChart::model'
qrc:/PieChartView.qml:24:17: Unable to assign [undefined] to QAbstractItemModel*
```

A stripped down version of my code is as follows:

**main.py**

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

from pie_chart import CustomPieChart

import qml_rc  # noqa: F401

# Need to register PieChartModel in here somehow...

def register_quick_items() -> None:
    qmlRegisterType(CustomPieChart, "Custom.CustomPieChart", 1, 0, "CustomPieChart")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    register_quick_items()

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**pie_chart_model.py**

```py
from typing import Dict

from PySide2.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, Qt


class PieChartModel(QAbstractListModel):
    _model_data: Dict[str, int]

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model_data = []

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
        return 2

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._model_data)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        # Not relevant

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # Not relevant

    def reset_with_data(self, model_data):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._model_data = model_data
        self.endResetModel()
```

**pie_chart.py**

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import Property, Signal, Slot
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickItem

from pie_chart_model import PieChartModel


class CustomPieChart(QQuickItem):
    model_changed = Signal(PieChartModel)
    _model: PieChartModel

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model = PieChartModel(parent)

    @Property(PieChartModel, notify=model_changed)
    def model(self):
        return self._model

    @Slot(result=None)
    def reset_model(self):
        pie_slices = {
            "A": 1,
            "B": 2,
            "C": 3
        }

        self._model.reset_with_data(pie_slices)
        self.model_changed.emit(self._model)
```

**PieChartView.qml**

```
import QtCharts 2.13
import QtQuick 2.13

import Custom.CustomPieChart 1.0

CustomPieChart {
    id: customPieChart

    Component.onCompleted: {
        customPieChart.reset_model()
    }

    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true
        animationOptions: ChartView.AllAnimations
        legend.visible: false

        PieSeries {
            id: pieSeries

            HPieModelMapper {
                model: customPieChart.model
                labelsRow: 0
                valuesRow: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    PieChartView {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

**qml.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>PieChartView.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the following errors:

You have the following errors:

- In C++ it is not necessary to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE or qRegisterMetaType so that the models can be accessed from QML, just register it as QObject in Q_Property, the same happens in PySide2.
- In a model that has 2 columns and n rows, it cannot be a QAbstractListModel, so you must change it to QAbstractTableModel.
- model must be a constant Property since in your logic you do not change it but only reset its information.
- Although I do not know if it is an error but if you want to see the data of the model in the ChartView you must associate it with a PieSeries.

Considering the above, the solution is:

**pie_chart_model.py**

```py
from typing import Dict

from PySide2.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex, Qt


class PieChartModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    _model_data: Dict[str, int]
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model_data = []

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
        return 2

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
        return len(self._model_data)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        r = index.row()
        c = index.column()
        if 0 <= r < self.rowCount() and 0 <= c < self.columnCount():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                if r == 0:
                    return list(self._model_data.keys())[c]
                elif r == 1:
                    return list(self._model_data.values())[c]

    def reset_with_data(self, model_data):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._model_data = model_data
        self.endResetModel()
```

**pie_chart.py**

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import Property, Slot, QObject
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickItem

from pie_chart_model import PieChartModel


class CustomPieChart(QQuickItem):
    _model: PieChartModel

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model = PieChartModel(self)

    @Property(QObject, constant=True)
    def model(self):
        return self._model

    @Slot(result=None)
    def reset_model(self):
        pie_slices = {
            "A": 1,
            "B": 2,
            "C": 3
        }

        self._model.reset_with_data(pie_slices)
```

**PieChartView.qml**

```
import QtCharts 2.13
import QtQuick 2.13

import Custom.CustomPieChart 1.0

CustomPieChart {
    id: customPieChart

    Component.onCompleted: {
        customPieChart.reset_model()
    }

    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true
        animationOptions: ChartView.AllAnimations
        legend.visible: false

        PieSeries{
            id: pie_series
        }

        HPieModelMapper {
            series: pie_series
            model: customPieChart.model
            labelsRow: 0
            valuesRow: 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of the items you pointed out were side-effects of my over simplified code...however, the real issue was your first bullet point and how I was registering my `@Property` decorator to have the type `PieChartModel` instead of `QObject`.  I don't fully understand why this was a problem since `PieChartModel` is a base of `QAbstractTableModel` which is a `QObject`.  I fell in love with Qt 10 years ago because of their documentation...most of the issues you've helped me solved are because of non-existent documentation and few examples.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue using PySide6. I had a `@Property(QAbstractListModel, constant=True)`, and kept getting the "Unable to handle unregistered datatype" error. Changing it to `@Property(QObject, constant=True)` fixed the problem, but I would also like to understand why that's necessary.

Comment: @maldata The error clearly points this out. When an object is exported to QML certain converters are used and they use certain types. So for any QObject(like QAbstractListModel) QObject should be used.